# Lambda Function that talks to DynamoDB and public API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a lambda function that talks to the dynamodb, fetches the record and then process the records and posts the response to a public api. When i created a Lambda function, it didnt have a VPC connected and it was able to talk to dynamodb but not to the public API. When i created a VPC and assign its private subnets it can still talk to the dynamodb. How can i have my lambda and VPC that talks to both dynamodb and also public API? Am new to AWS and please let me know if you need any other information.

Really appreciate the effort to read through the question.

Tried different options but still not able to call both dynamodb and api call in the same lamdba

Comment: You don't need VPC at all, if what you say is true. Tell us more about the original public API failures when you were not using VPC.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, your lambda is not able to connect the API hosted in EC2 regardless of the lambda being inside or outside of the VPC ? Is that correct ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention where the API exists, whether you run it on API Gateway or EC2 or something external to AWS.

Regardless, the same approach can work for all. First of all, DynamoDB is not a VPC service, it exists as a http endpoint in AWS service account.

For that reason, you are not required to have Lambda inside a private subnet to talk to DynamoDB. However, should you feel the requirement to have Lambda in a private subnet, your subnet must have network access to your API.

Typically that would be done using a NAT Gateway. A NAT gateway is a Network Address Translation (NAT) service. You can use a NAT gateway so that instances in a private subnet can connect to services outside your VPC but external services cannot initiate a connection with those instances.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html

Comment: Thanks mate. The API is running on a EC2 and connects through a load balancer. So whats the best way for me to achieve it?

Create a public subnet and access the API and dynamo db?

Comment: You can have the Lambda in the same subnet as your API, that way it can talk to the API using local network. You can enable vpc endpoint for DynamoDB, which will also allow you to talk to it locally with no additional costs.